# ClassCastException in Field.set()

Tags: java

- ## **Description**

  Here're two regular Java classes:

```
public class Country {
    private Building[] buildings;
}

public class Building {
    private String name;
    // etc.
}
```

And here is the method which throws `ClassCastException`:

```
public Object getInstanceWithReflection(class<?> clazz) {
    for (Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        // When the field is 'Buildings[]'
        // I'll call a method to get an array of buildings,
        // but the array is declared as 'Object[]', not 'Building[]'

        // pseudo code is as follows:
        // Object[] arr = new Object[len];
        // for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        //     arr[i] = getObject(Building.class, dataStr);
        // }
        field.set(target, arr); // throws ClassCastException: cannot cast Object[] to Building[]
    }
}

/* 
* @param str is a string which describes an object, just like json.
*/
public Object getObject(class<?> clazz, String str) {
    Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
    // parse the str
    // read data from str and inject the data into obj
    return obj;
}
```

- ## **PS**

  `getObject()` always returns a `Object`, but the actual type of the return value is `Building` in this context, and this method is not allowed to edit.
  And I cannot figure out how to cast `Object[]` into `Building[]`, as the only useful arg is `class<?> clazz` in method `getInstanceyWithReflection(class<?> clazz)`

Comment: It is good practice to guard any explicit casts with an instanceof check first: what is the data type of field variable?

Comment: Do you want to assign a value to member `buildings` of class `Country` via reflection?

Comment: @lolo Thanks for that! But the problem is, it's not allowed to cast Object[] into Building[] in Java, even the elems in the Object[] are all Building. So I need to find a way to do this.

Comment: so cast them if it possible, one by one and then create a list.

Comment: @Abra Yes it is. And I can only get ```Object``` through ```getObject()``` instead of ```Building```

Comment: @lolo But it's not good enough to me. Think about this situation: the method ```getXXXWithReflection(class<?> clazz)``` is not only used to create a ```Country```. If I want to get some other XXX instance with XXX.class, your solution may not work.

Comment: @lolo I mean the method ```getXXXWithReflection(class<?> clazz)``` is a general method, in this way I cannot program like ```Building b = (Building)getObject()``` because the target type is not sure, it depends on the ```class<?> clazz```

Comment: This is why you need to test if it's an instanceof ...

Comment: Which class contains method `getObject()` ?

Comment: @Abra updated already. Hope it'll help!